# Is there a way to avoid loops in OCaml using functional programming?

Tags: loops, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to program a cards game and at some point the user is asked:

"Submit the player's name or EXIT to start the game"

Therefore I need to ask this question until the user submits "EXIT", I've been told there is a way to do this without using loops.

So far all I had was:

```
printf("Ingrese el nombre del jugador o EXIT para comenzar el juego");;
print_newline;;
let command = read_line;;
```

And there I would use a loop:

```
while (command <> "EXIT") do
```

But was advised it is not good when doing functional-programming.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make Jeffrey's answer a bit prettier:

```
let rec read_until_exit () =
  match read_line () with
  | exception End_of_file -> ()
  | "EXIT" -> ()
  | s ->
    do_something_you_want_to_do_here_with_the_line s;
    read_until_exit ()
```

Comment: A bit of explanation. This feature (blending pattern-matching with exception-handling) has become available since OCaml 4.02. @JeffreyScofield implements a tail-recursive version, that is why it looks a bit complicated. A nice [blog post](https://blogs.janestreet.com/pattern-matching-and-exception-handling-unite/) explaining all this.

Comment: @AntonTrunov, this version is still tail-recursive.

Comment: Yes, I should have said that @Jeffrey's version implements a tail-recursive version without using this relatively new feature :)

Comment: The new feature is great, I will remember to use it henceforth! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just use a recursive function that terminates when command is "EXIT".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that reads lines of text from stdin until it sees a line consisting of the word EXIT (or the end of the file):

```
let rec read_until_exit () =
    match
        try Some (read_line ())
        with End_of_file -> None
    with
    | None -> ()
    | Some s -> 
        if s = "EXIT" then ()
        else
            begin
            do_something_you_want_to_do_here_with_the_line s;
            read_until_exit ()
            end
```

Comment: that case, when you don't get "EXIT" it only keeps the function going but you don't do anything? And also does the "()" mean to exit the function? how do I add another line in the end, by that I mean that I want the function to also create a new player on the last case

Comment: Yes, this function does nothing. It's just an example. The value `()` is returned by the function, but there's nothing special about it. You could have the function return any two values you like (of the same type). I'll add a comment showing where you could do things in the function. (As a side comment, I respectfully suggest you might want to work through an OCaml tutorial. You can't really guess your way through a new language.)

Comment: Nit: I can imagine a few ways of making this code a bit less ugly, see my answer below. :)